# unable to start cdap standalone server

Tags: server, cdap

I have cdap-sdk-3.0.0. When I try to start cdap server with instructions mentioned at location below:

http://docs.cask.co/cdap/current/en/developers-manual/getting-started/start-stop-cdap.html

I am getting below on console-

```
G:\Bigdata related\cdap-sdk-3.0.0>bin\cdap.bat restart
Stopping Standalone CDAP ...
Access is denied.
Starting Standalone CDAP...
```

Cdap server is unable to start. I am not getting issue. Required softwares are also installed in my machine like JDK7 and node.js

Any suggestions please..

Regards

Comment: start as the `sudo user`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you trying out CDAP standalone VM - http://cask.co/get-started?download=vm&version=3.0.0, this is contains CDAP SDK and all the required pre-requisites installed in an Ubuntu VM. CDAP standalone VM is a controlled environment to try out CDAP. You would just need to install virtual box https://www.virtualbox.org/ to get this going.

We have noticed that CDAP SDK doesn't work in some Windows environment and are working to fix it; CDAP-2504 is the JIRA to track (NOTE: I am unable to post more than two links in my response, hence just the JIRA number) . I would recommend you trying CDAP VM while we fix the windows version of the SDK.

Thanks,
Sree

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be, try to use docker container for run CDAP. Its easy to manage the services.